# multiload file xls in SheetJs

Tags: javascript, xls

i want try multiload xls files and view values in SheetJS but work only last in array url.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Excel to JSON Demo</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.7/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
/* set up XMLHttpRequest */

var url = new Array();
url.push("2017_01_Zole.xls");
url.push("2017_03_TK.xls");
url.push("2017_05_Psy.xls");

for(var z = 0; z<url.length; z++){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url[z], true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function(e) {
      var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

      /* convert data to binary string */
      var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
      var arr = new Array();
      for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      var bstr = arr.join("");

      /* Call XLSX */
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});

      /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      /* Get worksheet */
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
     // jsn = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});
      console.log(worksheet['F3'].v +' = '+ worksheet['J3'].v);

    };
    oReq.send();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After each loop I want to display the result in console.log. Unfortunately, it only shows me data from the last file.

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> EDIT:
>   Problem solved
>
> ```
> var x = 0;
> function xlsy(urls){
>     var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     oReq.open("GET", urls, true);
>     //.......
>     oReq.send();
>     x++;
>     if(x < url.length){
>         xlsy(url[x])
>     }
> }
> xlsy(url[0]);
> ```